# portable native client system info

Tags: google-nativeclient

I know Google Portable Native Client have api to get number of CPU cores

like this :

```
`long result = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);`
```

but is there any way to get the total available memory, GPU(type,memory e.t.c)?
or current cpu load?
Thank you